# For any graph G, How do I find the algorithm that returns the permutation of vertices with minimum bandwidth?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a graph $G$, is there an algorithm that returns the ordering of vertices with minimum bandwidth?

The bandwidth of an ordering of vertices, $f: V(G) \rightarrow \{1, 2, \ldots, |V(G)|\}$ is given by $$\max\{|f(v_i) - f(v_j)| : (v_i, v_j) \in E(G)\}$$

For example, let $V(G) = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and $E(G) = \left\{\{a,b\}, \{b,d\}, \{a,c\}\right\}$. Then, the ordering $(a, b, c, d)$ has bandwidth two (consider the edges $\{a, c\}$ or $\{b, d\}$).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-complete -- you have to check every permutation. Moreover, short of really stupid examples, there aren't any nice types of graphs, even trees, for which there is a polynomial-time algorithm.

Nonetheless, there are plenty of nice heuristics for finding reorderings of the vertices which reduce the bandwidth of the graph, for example the [Cuthill-McKee algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill-McKee_algorithm). The idea is really simple: pick a starting vertex and breadth-first search through the graph, labeling the order in which you visited all the nodes. That's the order of the vertices in the new permutation.

You should look [here](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBA77/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK3/NODE137.HTM) and [here](http://ciprian-zavoianu.blogspot.com/2009/01/project-bandwidth-reduction.html) for further info.

Comment: (a) "you have to check every permutation" is simply not true (perhaps this is hyperbole?), and (b) it can be calculated in polynomial time for interval graphs (which I don't think is a "really stupid example"); see e.g. Kleitman and Vohra "Computing the bandwidth of interval graphs".  (Aside from this, it's a great answer.)

Comment: (a) I'm exaggerating yes, but it's still O(n!) right?

(b) I stand corrected! I didn't know about interval graphs but the maximal clique ordering property would make it much easier to order them nicely. The "stupid example" I'm thinking of is the matrix discretizing a differential operator in 1D.